# Jquery stop rotation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function(){ 
    var camera, renderer;
    var mpi=Math.PI /180;
    var circleRadius = 1000;
    var startAngle = 0;
    var centerX = 0;
    var centerZ = 0;
    var startRadians = startAngle + mpi;
    var totalSpheres = 4;
    var incrementAngle = 360/totalSpheres;
    var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi;
 var Element = function ( id, dat, position, rotation ) {
      var html = [
        '<div class="wrapper" >',
        '<ul class="stage clearfix">',
        '<li class="scene" >',
               '<div class="movie i1" id="' + id + '" >',
          
        
               '</div>',
                  '</li>',
        
         
                  
                                 '</ul>',
         '</div>'
       ].join('\n');
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      $(div).html(html);
                           
      
      var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( div );
      object.position.x = position.x;
      object.position.y = position.y;
      object.position.z = position.z;
      object.rotation.x = rotation.x;
      object.rotation.y = rotation.y;
      object.rotation.z = rotation.z;
      
      return object;
     
      } 
   
   init();
    animate();
            
      function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight*.85);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10 );
    camera.position.set(-100,60,4000);
                camera.updateMatrix(); // make sure camera's local matrix is updated
                camera.updateMatrixWorld(); // make sure camera's world matrix is updated
                camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );
    var group = new THREE.Group();
   
              
                 var str = {
     "attacker":$.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {  
     console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
 }}),
     "defender":$.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/defender.html",
        success: function (data) {  
     console.log(data);
            $("#defender").append(data)
 }}),
                   
                    "goalkeeper" : $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {  
     console.log(data);
            $("#goalkeeper").append(data)
 }}),
                      "midfielder":$.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/midfielder.html",
        success: function (data) {  
     console.log(data);
            $("#midfielder").append(data)
 }})
                   
    
                 }
                
   var allKeys = Object.keys(str);
              

    for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {
                    var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
     var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;
                  
                    group.add( new Element( allKeys[i], str[i], new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0), 0) ) );
     startRadians += incrementRadians; 
     
                    
      }
        scene.add(group);
                    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
     
   
//controls.enabled = false;
controls.center =  new THREE.Vector3(
    scene.position.x,
    scene.position.y,
    scene.position.z
);
      //  controls.addMouseHandler(renderer.domElement, drag, zoomIn, zoomOut);
       controls.update();
   
    
   }
   
  $(document).on('mouseover', ".scene",function() {
    $(this).rotation.y = 0; 
    // or try once scene.rotation.y = false;
    // or try once scene.rotation.y = 0;  
 });
   
   


   function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    scene.rotation.y-=0.001;
    
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
    
    
   }
  
   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
```

I have this dynamically created html structure.

```
var html = [
            '<div class="wrapper" >',
            '<ul class="stage clearfix">',
            '<li class="scene" >',
            '<div class="movie i1" id="' + id + '" >',
            '</div>',
            '</li>',
            '</ul>',
            '</div>'
            ].join('\n');
```

I am populating this with the help of ajax and then finally adding the divs to the sphere.
At last, I wrote this animate function which rotates the sphere on the y axis.

```
function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
            scene.rotation.y-=0.001;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );


        }
```

What I wanted to do is to stop the rotation upon hovering on the div so I did:

```
   $( ".scene" ).mouseover(function() {
    scene.rotation.y = false;
   });
```

But it isn't working for some reason.

Comment: `scene.rotation.y = 0` does not work?

Comment: can you show more code? how are you using `html`?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. tried that already

Comment: The whole code is kind of messy. But I can post that. wait for a minute

Comment: check I have posted the whole script for you @Dij